# Error: The reference to entity "name" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: xml

Why would I be getting the following error in my XML file?

> 17:52 sample.xml  The reference to entity "_Ghee" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: From what you show, the answer is probably that the delimiter is missing. Would you like to actually show the problematic input? Then it would be possible to discuss the details you are looking at.

Comment: Please read [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ , https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file immediately before `_Ghee`, is an ampersand character (`&`).  A `&` may appear in an XML file in parsed data only as an entity reference of the form `&` ***name*** `;`.

In your case, ***name*** is `_Ghee`, but you've forgotten the `;`.  Or, more likely, you actually desired an ampersand to be present as itself ahead of `_Ghee`.  In that case you should change `&` to `&amp;`.